# break looping in json jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

how can I break for looping in get json jquery when the condition has reached the right value? I've tried to set variable inside json query code then break it, but it cannot read the variable when the variable is outside of json query code. is there any possible to break that for loop?

here's my scripts.

```
 <?php
  $array = array("test.com","test2.com");
 ?>    

<script type="text/javascript">
var variable, x=0;
var web= <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
for(a=0;a<web.length;a++){
    $.getJSON('http://www.'+web[a]+'/checkdomain.php?z=1',function (data) {
        variable = data.showText;
        console.log(variable);
        if(variable=="there is a value here") {
         top.frames['mywebsite'].location.href="http://www."+web[a];
         x= 1;          
        }else {
         x= 0;
        }
    });

    if(x==1){
     break;
    }else {
     continue;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: `return false` is not working for you ?

Comment: I've tried, but it's not working. @NishitMaheta

Comment: Your `$.getJSON()` results are asynchronous.  They arrive LATER, long after the `for` loop has already completed.  You can't write the code this way because this launches all your Ajax calls in parallel.  Are you trying to do these `$.getJSON()`calls in sequence (not starting the next one until the prior one is done)?

Comment: If you want to stop loop after it reaches the right value than simply assign end value to "a" like a=web.length-1 inside ur loop

Comment: You can write the return statement when want to terminate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not working because you retrieving data inside for loop.So what happen with you code is that ,
 - First, for loop is not waiting for AJAX call's response. It will execute your code sequentially.
 - Second, so when getJSON response came from server side, might be possible that your for loop will be completed.

So, you should try with some recursive function.

```
function retrieveData(index){
     $.getJSON('http://www.'+web[index]+'/checkdomain.php?z=1',function (data) {
        variable = data.showText;
        console.log(variable);
        if(variable=="there is a value here") {
         top.frames['mywebsite'].location.href="http://www."+web[index];
//         x= 1;          

        }else {
//         x= 0;
           index++;
           retrieveData(index);
        }
    });

}
retrieveData(0);
```

Hope this might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If ajax acts synchronously(which it does not not) your code would be like this: you need to set          a=web.length-1; inside loop if condition is matched

```
   <?php
  $array = array("test.com","test2.com");
  ?>    

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var variable, x=0;
 var web= <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
 for(a=0;a<web.length;a++){
 $.getJSON('http://www.'+web[a]+'/checkdomain.php?z=1',function (data) {
    variable = data.showText;
    console.log(variable);
    if(variable=="there is a value here") {

     top.frames['mywebsite'].location.href="http://www."+web[a];
     a=web.length-1;
     x= 1;          
    }else {
     x= 0;
    }
});

if(x==1){
 break;
}else {
 continue;
}

}
</script>
```

But since ajax is asynchronous so it's better you do it using recursive function like this

```
  var a=0;
  function re(a){
   $.getJSON('http://www.'+web[a]+'/checkdomain.php?z=1',function (data) {
    variable = data.showText;
    console.log(variable);
    if(variable=="there is a value here") {

     top.frames['mywebsite'].location.href="http://www."+web[a];

     x= 1;
    return;          
    }else {
     x= 0;
    }
});
a++
re(a);

  }
```